# Search for Employee name through ID (sifting through array)

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on a code that reads an input from a txt file, and creates an array of Employees. I'm stuck at the last stage of code, where I'd like it to prompt the user for an Employee ID, and then outputs a name that matches that ID number.

Here is my current code:

My header (Employee.h)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const unsigned int NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES = 5;

struct Employee
{
  string name;
  int id;
  double salary;
};

void printEmployee(const Employee& c);
Employee readEmployee();
//----Add findEmployee prototype for Step 2----
int findEmployee(const Employee array[],int tId,int num);
```

My function code (Employee.cpp)

```
#include "Employee.h"

void printEmployee(const Employee& c)
{
  cout << "The Employee info is: " << c.name << ", ";
  cout << c.id << ", $";
  cout << c.salary << endl;
}

Employee readEmployee()
{
    Employee tempEmp;
    cout << "Employee Name?: ";
    getline(cin, tempEmp.name);   // command to input a string
    cout << "Employee ID?: ";
    cin >> tempEmp.id;
    cout << "Employee Yearly Salary? ";
    cin >> tempEmp.salary;
      
    return tempEmp;
}

int findEmployee()
{
    Employee array[NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES];
    int i;

    for (int i = 0; i<NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES; i++)
    {
         array[i]=readEmployee();
         cin.ignore(256,'\n'); 
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES; i++)
    {
         printEmployee(array[i]);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

My main (main.cpp)

```
#include "Employee.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  // declare an array of Employees
  Employee employeeArray[NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES];
  // declare a variable to store index of Employees array where the id was found
  int employeeIndex;
  // declare a variable to store the Employee id to search for in array
  int employeeId;

  cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

  // read in data for each employee
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES; i++)
  {
    employeeArray[i] = readEmployee();
    cin.ignore(256, '\n');
  }
  cout << endl;
  // print out data for each employee
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES; i++)
  {
    printEmployee(employeeArray[i]);
  }

  //----Add code below for Step2----
  // prompt the user for an id
  cout << "Enter an id to look for: ";
  cin >> employeeId;
  // call the findEmployee function
  employeeIndex = findEmployee(employeeArray, employeeId, NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES);
  // if found, display the name of the employee that goes with the id
    
}
```

I've tried to create an employee function in my function cpp file that searches through the input function. I literally cannot figure out a way to implement that into my main.

My assignment says:

> Define the findEmployee function in Employee.cpp the following are the specifications: Arguments: array: array of Employee(s) tId: the id you are searching for num: the size of the array Returns: -1 if the id is not found an index to the array of Employees where the id was found Add code in main to call the findEmployee function and print out the corresponding name to go with the id.

Unfortunately I am not allowed to use anything more advanced like eg `std::vector`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Don't tag a C++ question with the C and C# tags unless you're particularly fond of downvotes.  You're programming in C++; that's the only language tag that is relevant.

Comment: Can't you search for `employeeId` inside `employeeArray`? First of all add the required parameters for `findEmployee`, its declaration and definition don't match.

Comment: `findEmployee()` should not be reading or printing the list of employees.

Comment: @Ripi2, Thanks for the comment. How would I search for employeeId inside of employeeArray? My final product should have an if call, where if it finds the ID, it prints a name, if an ID is not found, then it returns a -1 and outputs that there was an error. I just genuinely don't know what to write to make that happen, lol. By declaration and definition do you mean what I use to call it in my main.cpp file is different from what I call for it in my employee.cpp file?

Comment: You can just make a simple loop if you don't know about standard algorithms yet. Imagine if you had a stack of papers with 1 employee's info on each page. How would you find an employee in such a stack of papers? One solution in `c++` would be the same as this.

Comment: @drescherjm I can remove the read and print functions from my find function, but I'm not sure how to make it so the loop inside of my findEmployee function reads the array I have made ...

Comment: You don't want to read the array again in findEmployee(). Use the array parameter you passed from main(): `int findEmployee(const Employee array[],int tId,int num);`

Comment: @drescherjm I'm confused. How do I use the findEmployee function to locate IDs then, if my IDs are all stored inside an array?

Comment: The declaration of `findEmployee` at `Employee.h`is right. Copy it to its definition at `Employee.cpp`. The usage of this function now agrees to its call at `main.cpp`.  Notice we'll pass an array (copy of) instead of a pointer to that array. The array contains elements of type `Employee`, a struct that has a member `id`. So, `employeeArray[i].id` is the id for element at pos 'i'. Write a loop that compares each of these ids in the array with the one you pass in the function call. Return '-1' if not found or that `'i' that matches the given id.

Comment: actually your code is not that wrong. I mean some of the right parts are already present. There should be some error though that you should include in the question. The error message already tells a lot about how the code can be fixed. If you do not understand the error message no problem, include it in the question and someone will be able to help you understand it

Answer (score 1):

In your code there are 2 seperate distinct arrays. Rather than reading the input again in `findEmployee` you want to find the element in the array `employeeArray` declared in `main`. To do that you could pass the array to the function.

However, learn about standard [container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for arrays and [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to find an element that matches some predicate.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

constexpr size_t num_employees = 5;

struct Employee
{
  std::string name;
  int id = 0;
  double salary = 0.0;
};

Employee read() {
    // mock only
    static int dummy_id = 0;
    return {"",dummy_id++,0.0};
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Employee> employees;
    for (size_t i=0;i<num_employees;++i) {
        employees.push_back(read());
    }

    int needle = 1;

    auto it = std::find_if(employees.begin(),
                        employees.end(),
                        [=](const Employee& e){
                            return e.id == needle;
                        });
    if (it != employees.end()) 
        std::cout << "index = " << std::distance(employees.begin(),it);
}
```

`std::find_if` returns an iterator to the element. When no element was found that matches the predicate (`id == needle`) the end iterator is returned. [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) can be used to get the distance to the begin iterator, which is the desired index.

Comment: We haven't gone over simple algorithms yet. I can't use pointers or algorithms. I'm trying to find a way to do it the way given to me by my assignment instructions, which I can paste in here:

Define the findEmployee function in Employee.cpp the following are the specifications:
Arguments:
array: array of Employee(s)
tId: the id you are searching for
num: the size of the array
Returns:
-1 if the id is not found
an index to the array of Employees where the id was found
 
Add code in main to call the findEmployee function and print out the corresponding name to go with the id.

Comment: @Yev thats a pity. They are teaching you C not C++. In C++, using raw C arrays is the diificult complicated way while `std::vector` and `std::array` are so much more beginner friendly. They must have told you how to pass an array to a function, did they?

Comment: "I can't use pointers or algorithms" I suppose you mean "iterators" not "pointers", because there is no pointer in my code, but if you are limited to C arrays you must use a pointer.

Comment: @Yev and please note that such restrictions should be mentioned in the question. You really wouldn't use C arrays for this task unless you are forced to

Comment: yeaah, that's exactly what they're telling us. Our lab instructor doesn't do any actual teaching, and all I can do is try and find problems that are similar and watch videos on them. I haven't had any luck thus far. They all use code that we haven't gone over or aren't allowed to use. And I don't know how to implement what they're asking for with what we are given...

Comment: Tell your teacher to read this : [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) and update his teaching material. We've stopped living in 1998 for a long time now.

Comment: @Yev this is a good video on the topic https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk. But otherwise I strongly recommend against youtube videos. There is too much garbage out there. Rather get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Or if you can't get hold of a recent (!) C++ book this site will do too : https://www.learncpp.com/

Comment: Or show him this video [Stop teaching "C", from cppcon 2015!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk)

Comment: @Yev unfortunately, if your teacher missed to explain you how to use C arrays but asks you to use them in an assignment, there isnt much we can do about that bigger issue here. As a matter of fact, explaining how to use `std::vector` can be done within minutes, but proper explaining how C arrays work requires a deep dive into the history of C++ as descendant of C. Its sad that still today C++ teaching has this kind of problem and people that should know better treat C++ as C with some minor addons which it isnt. I'd rewrite the answer, but have to leave unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

1. Change your `int findEmployee()` function signature to match the required parameters. You call it with

   ```
   findEmployee(employeeArray, employeeId, NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES);
   ```

so something like that:

```
   findEmployee(Employee employeeArray[], int employeeId, int num);
```

2. You are already using `for` loops like this:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES; i++)
   ```

Just chek if the ID of the employee at index `i` matches `employeeId` - then return that `i`.

3. If you got out of the loop - it measn that the ID ws not found, so return `-1`

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the findEmployee function so that it accepts a pointer to the employeeArray which was defined in main, as well as the employeeId you are searching for and the length of the employeeArray. Then, within findEmployee you do not need to define a new array. You can instead just iterate directly through the employeeArray, and compare each Employees id against the desired employee id that was passed into the function. Then, when you find the employee you were looking for, you can have the function return the id of the employee in the employeeArray.

Comment: I was told not to use pointers in my code if I'm not wrong. I was just told to call the findEmployee function in the main, search for an ID, and output an if (if id found, output a name, if id isn't found, return -1 and output an error).

Comment: @Yev "...if I'm not wrong." you are wrong. `int findEmployee(const Employee array[],int tId,int num);` here `array` **is** a pointer. They do want you to pass a pointer to the function. You can read about array to pointer decay here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-conversion-aka-decay

Comment: @Yev Impossible to do this without using pointers. You cannot pass an array by value in C++. You must pass a pointer to the array into the function